# Unzip file with php?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a scrip that downloads a zip archive and I need to extract the contents to the directory that zip archive is in. I have tried various things, this being the last:

```
mkdir("/home/site/public_html/".$db."", 0777);

    $url  = 'http://wordpress.org/latest.zip';
    $path = "/home/site/public_html/".$db."/latest.zip";

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    file_put_contents($path, $data);

    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    $zip->open("/home/site/public_html/".$db."/latest.zip");
    $zip->extractTo("/home/site/public_html/".$db."/");
    $zip->close();
```

The zip files downloads just fine but it won't extract. Is there another way I can extract the files?

Comment: Not sure I follow, doesn't `extatcTo()` extract the contents of the zip file used in `open()` to the path you pass as an argument?

Comment: Well, ideally yes, that is what should happen but it doesn't. The zip file downloads but doesn't extract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a permissions error; it's common for many hosting providers (and good security practice) for the web user (what PHP is running as) to to have limited permissions, such as no write within web directories.  See if you can get more information on the failure by upping the `error_reporting` level (http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php), and if this is the issue, it can be solved with suexec. (http://www.alain.knaff.lu/howto/PhpSuexec/)  Be careful!

Comment: Even though the zip downloads ok, there could still be a permissions problem when extracting that file?

Comment: It was a permission problem. I needed to give the correct folder read/write privileges. Thanks!

Comment: Great!  However, a security flaw in your application could lead to other data being deleted.  Try to avoid keeping anything else important in that folder.